# After being integrated into our advertising system, when testing with Splash’s video test id, the ads never load

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

After being integrated into our advertising system, when using Splash's video test id test, the ad will never load, but the image id test is always good
The reason why the video splash cannot be loaded has been found: if the visibiltiy of SplashView=GONE, calling SplashView.loadAd() does not seem to work
but
If it did not work before, it will not work after the visibility in the code is changed to VISIBLE, unless the app data is clear...
If the splashView itself is visible but the visibility of one of its ancestor views is gone, it will not work. The situation we encountered is actually this situation
This kind of problem only occurs when the media is video, and image does not have this problem

Comment: Did you mean,  visibility of ancestor or parent view of SplashView has set to GONE? In that case SplashView
won't be VISIBLE since parent view is INVISIBLE.
Please post your code/xml for more details.

For Splash Video Ads integration please check this example and sample code.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-splash-0000001050066919

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you set `frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` before  `splashView.load()`.

and If the request fails, then set to `GONE`.